# Changing breadcrumb according to user parameters in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, breadcrumbs, mvcsitemapprovider

I use MvcSiteMapProvider to add Breadcrumbs to my site. 
I want to change breadcrumb trail according to parameters used in ActionResult.
So, link looks like this:
`localhost:49345/Evaluation/ChoicePeriod?typeControl=Input`

Current view of SiteMapPath:
`Main > Evaluation`

Expected view:
`Main > Evaluation > Input`

Routes:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Evaluation",
            url: "Evaluation/ChoicePeriod/{action}/{typeControl}",
            defaults: new { action = "Index", typeControl = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Sitemap:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Main" controller="Main" action="Index">
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Evaluation" area="Evaluation" controller="ChoicePeriod" action="Index" >
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Input" area="Evaluation" controller="ChoicePeriod" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="typeControl" key="typeControl"/>
 </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

I've added typeControl value to RouteValues and now i don't know how to show it in SiteMapPath

```
    public ActionResult Index(string typeControl, int? id_pred)
    {
        var node = MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Current.FindSiteMapNodeFromKey("typeControl");
        if (node != null)
        {
            node.RouteValues["typeControl"] = typeControl;
        }
        ...
```

Is there any way to make my breadcrumbs look like i expected to? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `typeControl=""` parameter to the `Evaluation` node to force a non-match when it has a value.

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Main" controller="Main" action="Index">
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Evaluation" area="Evaluation" controller="ChoicePeriod" action="Index" typeControl="">
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Input" area="Evaluation" controller="ChoicePeriod" action="Index" preservedRouteParameters="typeControl" key="typeControl"/>
 </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

Also, you should update your route so it will generate the same URL that it matches, and so that it supplies a `controller` RouteValue since it is required by MVC.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Evaluation",
    url: "Evaluation/ChoicePeriod",
    defaults: new { controller = "ChoicePeriod", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: Thanks! It works, but result is the same for different typeControl values. What should i do if i have multiple nodes with `typeControl` parameter? I have tried to add `key="typeControl"` to them, but it doesn't work.

Comment: `preservedRouteParamters` is for forcing a match to any node. Typically when using it is necessary to use the `SiteMapTitle` attribute to dynamically update the title. But the default behavior (without `preservedRouteParameters`) expects you to configure 1 node for every possible route value combination. You would use `typeControl="Input"` in that case. See this article: http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/09/02/how-to-make-mvcsitemapprovider-remember-a-user-position

Answer (score 0):

Using [MvcBreadCrumbs](https://github.com/thelarz/MvcBreadCrumbs) you can add code like this your controller:

```
public class SampleController : Controller
{
    [BreadCrumb]
    public ActionResult GetProduct(int id)
    {
        var model = db.GetProduct(id);
        BreadCrumb.SetLabel("Product " + model.ProductName);
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Then display it on View.cshtml like this:

```
@Html.Raw(BreadCrumb.Display())
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use URL in your mvc.sitemap:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Main" controller="Main" action="Index">
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Evaluation" area="Evaluation" controller="ChoicePeriod" action="Index" >
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Input" area="Evaluation" controller="ChoicePeriod" action="Index" url="/Evaluation/ChoicePeriod/Input"/>
 </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```